# Generate Transaction ID PHP

Tags: onsubmit

I am making a fees collecting module for a college  in php, On submit, I want to echo voucher number, every time the voucher number should be +1 to previous voucher. And every day the voucher number should start from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a DB table to store the current voucher number and the date.
On every submit you :

1. Check if the date is today's date. If not you reset the voucher number
2. Increment it

And try a little research before asking next time.

Comment: There is a column in the database as voucher num autoincrement. I dont know how to echo that. Can someone give me code.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is meant for id columns: it is incremented on each `INSERT` so you don't have to bother managing you ids. In your case, you will have to manage your voucher number manually, with `UPDATE` queries. If you don't know how to display values from your database in PHP, I suggest you start with reading the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php).

Comment: Ok Means on every insert I have to insert the voucher_num manually by incrementing previous voucher and echo the same.

Comment: Yes you can do that, if you really want to keep track of your voucher number.